# Как наполнить таблицу случайными записями, если id нужно брать из другой таблицы случайно?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Как наполнить таблицу 10000 случайными записями, при том что `id` (`empno`) нужно брать из другой таблицы в случайном порядке? Где `id` четырехзначные числа, идут не по порядку.

Код ниже выводит один `id` на все 10000 записей. Была идея через `level`, но все равно выводит один `id` на все записи, хоть убирай `level`, хоть оставляй, одно и тоже.

```
insert into prodal
  (kto_prodal, tovar_id, kol_vo, p_data)
  SELECT 
         ((select empno
             from (select empno from emp order by dbms_random.value)
            where rownum = 1)+level-level), 
            dbms_random.value(1, 5), 
            dbms_random.value(1, 20), 
            (to_date(sysdate, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
            +dbms_random.value(1, 365) 
            +dbms_random.value(1, 23) / 24 
            +dbms_random.value(1, 59) / 24 / 60 ) 
            FROM dual connect by level <= 10000;
```

Вот что получается. Справа столбец `empno`, из которого надо взять `id` и рандомно вставить на 10000 срок с повторением:

[image: картинка]

Еще условие, можно использовать только один dml запрос.

Comment: Не могли бы вы в вопросе сделать минимальный пример данных и привести ожидаемый результат?

Comment: Из столбца empno(из другой таблицы) взять 14 id и рандомно вставить на 10000 срок с повторением

Comment: В данный момент берет один случайный id и пихает во все строки.

Comment: Никогда не вставвляйте в вопрос картинки, их нельзя скопировать. Данные должны быть только текстом. Ну ладно, вашу задачу понял.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот та часть запроса, которая вызывает проблему:

```
create table emp (empno) as 
    select column_value from sys.odciNumberList (7369,7499,7566,7788)
/
select (
    select empno from (
        select empno 
        from emp 
        order by dbms_random.random) where rownum = 1) empno 
from dual d connect by level <= 10
/

     EMPNO
----------
      7369
      7369
[...]
      7369

10 rows selected.
```

Вы ожидали, что подзапрос выполнится в каждой строке N раз. Но это не так.
Между основным запросом и скалярным подзапросом нет корреляции, поэтому оптимизатор решил выполнить подзапрос *только один раз* и выводить его результат в каждой строке основного запроса.

Самое простое, встроить в подзапрос корреляцию с основным запросом, условие для которой всегда выполнится в `true`.

Или так:

```
select (
    select  empno from (
        select empno 
        from emp 
        order by dbms_random.random) where s.lvl is not null and rownum = 1) empno,
    date'2021-01-01'+numToDsInterval(trunc(dbms_random.value(0, 60*24*365)),'minute') dt
from (select level lvl from dual connect by level <= 10) s
```

Или лучше так:

```
select (
    select max (empno) keep (dense_rank first order by dbms_random.random)
    from emp where s.lvl > 0) empno,
    date'2021-01-01'+numToDsInterval(trunc(dbms_random.value(0, 60*24*365)),'minute') dt
from (select level lvl from dual connect by level <= 10) s
```

Результат будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
     EMPNO DT                 
---------- -------------------
      7499 2021-03-31 04:26:00
      7566 2021-08-31 15:59:00
[...]
      7788 2021-10-05 09:54:00

10 rows selected.
```